# About PHPsession concept

Tags: php, session

**shopping.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
    $a=$_POST['prod'];
    $b=$_POST['qty'];
    $_SESSION[$a]=$b;    
}    
?> 
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="Billing.php">

Select any Product:
<select name="prod">
   <option>Nokia</option>
   <option>Reliance</option>
   <option>Samsung</option>
   <option>LG</option>
</select>

<br><br>
Quantity:<input name="qty"> <br><br>

<input type="submit" name="sub" value="ADD">
</form>
</body></html>
```

**Billing.php**

```
<html>
<head>

<?php  
session_start();
echo session_id();
echo "<br>";
echo "selected products are:<br>";
// print_r($_SESSION);
foreach($_SESSION as $x=>$y){  
   echo "product is $x and Quantity is:$y<br>";
}
?>
</head> </html>
```

**output**

```
 Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - 
 headers already sent by (output started at E:\PHP programs\Billing.php:2) in   E:\PHP     programs\Billing.php on line 4

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - 
headers already sent (output started at E:\PHP programs\Billing.php:2) in E:\PHP programs\Billing.php on line 4
```

Please, any one give the solution for the above Warning messages and how can I get the successful execution of a program?

Comment: Try to create more accurate question titles. "About xy" will help no one in the future..

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `session_start();`  before any kind out output (at first line of file). `session_start` needs to send a cookie header which will fail if you've sent any output to user.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
**shopping.php**

<html>

<head>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
```

Answer (score 2):

`SESSION` must be at the top of your file. start code with the `session_start();`.

It looks like you have first declared `<html>` and then you have started session in `billing.php` just make changes as follows...

**Billing.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<html>
<head>
```

Answer (score 0):

** Billing.php **

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
```

Remove any new lines, or any kind of output you might have before `session_start` in your php files that generating that error you posted.

Comment: Ahh thanks; First line wasn't a comment in the file but to show the name of the file. Your edit is more organized though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be you are trying to do something like this... check this out there are two files like you have created. The main thing you forgot to do is session_start() in your first file. So $_SESSION acted as an user created array variable rather than the session variable.

```
<?
    //you always need to start session before using the session in php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
    $a=$_POST['prod'];
    $b=$_POST['qty'];
    $_SESSION[$a]=$b;  

    // check if its being added in the session or not
    print_r($_SESSION);  
}    
?> 

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
Select any Product:
<select name="prod">
<option>Nokia</option>
<option>Reliance</option>
<option>Samsung</option>
<option>LG</option>
</select>
<br><br>
Quantity:<input name="qty"> <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="ADD">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<? 
    //it is best way to close the session at the end of the file
    session_close();
?>


<? session_start();?>
<html>
<head><title>Billing.php file</title></head>
<body>
<?php
echo session_id();
echo "<br>";
echo "selected products are:<br>";
 print_r($_SESSION);

foreach($_SESSION as $x=>$y){
    echo "product is $x and Quantity is:$y<br>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```